# Gulp - How to append to the dest instead of replace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, gulp

I have a code like:

```
gulp.task('concat-uglify-js', function() {
  return gulp.src(src + 'js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('angular-filemanager.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst))
});

gulp.task('cache-templates', function () {
  return gulp.src(tplPath + '/*.html')
    .pipe(templateCache('cached-templates.js', {
      module: 'FileManagerApp',
      base: function(file) {
        return tplPath + '/' + path.basename(file.history);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
});
```

And I want to merge this two tasks output in one file... "angular-filemanager.min.js"

There are an option to do something like

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(dst, {mode: "APPEND_INSTEAD_OF_REPLACE"}));
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this but try using [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter):

```
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('concat-uglify-js', function() {

  var filter = {
    html: gulpFilter('*.html'),
    js  : gulpFilter('*.js')
  };

  return gulp
    .src([src + 'js/*.js', tplPath + '/*.html'])
    .pipe(filter.html)
    .pipe(templateCache('cached-templates.js', {
      module: 'FileManagerApp',
      base: function(file) {

        return tplPath + '/' + path.basename(file.history);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(filter.html.restore)
    .pipe(filter.js)
    .pipe(concat('angular-filemanager.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not helpful for now, since it is not yet [released](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/releases), but [`gulp.dest`](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpdestpath-options) in 4.0 will [add an `overwrite` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/issues/30) that defaults to true but can be set to false for appending:

`.pipe(gulp.dest(path, { overwrite: false }))`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the call to `templateCache` in a function and then use [`add-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-stream) to combine that function's output with the stream of js files in the `concat-uglify-js` task.

I'm not sure what angular template cache plugin you're using but I wrote about this situation in more detail [here](http://paulsalaets.com/pre-caching-angular-templates-with-gulp/).

```
var addStream = require('add-stream');

gulp.task('concat-uglify-js', function() {
  return gulp.src(src + 'js/*.js')
    // add js file containing cached templates to stream of js files
    .pipe(addStream.obj(cacheTemplates()))
    .pipe(concat('angular-filemanager.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst))
});

// is this task still needed?
gulp.task('cache-templates', function () {
  return cacheTemplates()
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dst));
});

// this returns a stream of one js file
function cacheTemplates() {
  return gulp.src(tplPath + '/*.html')
    // (you may want to minify html here)
    .pipe(templateCache('cached-templates.js', {
      module: 'FileManagerApp',
      base: function(file) {
        return tplPath + '/' + path.basename(file.history);
      }
    }));
}
```